# Passing innerHTML to an element and attaching event

Tags: javascript, html, events, callback

I have to pass `innerHTML` to a div using my JavaScript function.
The `innerHTML` that I am passing also has a `div` for which I have to attach a click event so that on click of it, the element responds to the click event.

I have a fiddle here to explain the problem:
**http://jsfiddle.net/K2aQT/2/**

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="containerFrame">
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){usersFunction();};

function usersFunction(){
    var someHtml = '<div> <div class ="btnSettings"> </div> <span></span> </div>';
    changeSource(someHtml);
}

function changeSource(newSource){
    document.getElementById("containerFrame").innerHTML = newSource;
}
```

While passing the source, how do I tell JavaScript function that this HTML being passed also has some element which has to be bound to a click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to do it this way, you could consider adding the click handler inside the HTML string itself:

```
var someHtml = '<div> <div class ="btnSettings" onclick="return myFunction()"> </div> <span></span> </div>';
```

Alternatively, after modifying the `.innerHTML`, find the right `<div>`:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('containerFrame');
frame.innerHTML = newSource;
var settings = frame.getElementsByClassName('btnSettings')[0];

// depends on the browser, some IE versions use attachEvent()
settings.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
}, false);
```

Comment: Is that an elegant method or is there no other way? Since the user is passing the `source`, does it mean that he'll be attaching the click event as well? But as I said, when that particular button is clicked, from inside my plugin, I have to pass additional information as well. how will I handle that in this casE?

Comment: And I tried with `return myfunction()`. Not able to get the lcikc event working here on that red div. http://jsfiddle.net/9LJBY/1/

Comment: @user1240679 No, I wouldn't call it very clean; updated answer with another way.

Comment: @user1240679 Well, did you define `myfunction()`?

Comment: I got the point of finding the right div. But that function is inside a plugin and I am not sure if I should be hardcoding to find the right div to attach the event handler to it. Could this still be improvised in some way? Let's say the user changes the class of the `button div` that was passed, how would that be handled?

Comment: @user1240679 I think I'm missing some background as to what your plugin is supposed to do, because afaict this answer covers the question as it stands now.

Comment: The fiddle I made has a `changeSource` function which is inside my plugin (as I mentioned there in the fiddle). So when a user passes the source (and the user might change the source later as well), I can't code inside the plugin to find a specific class to attach a click event (since the source passed by the user might change and the plugin will stop working when it tries to find that element to attach click event). How do I tackle this?

Comment: @user1240679 so what element should the handler be attached to? The frame?

Comment: I have a click event handler for the main `containerFrame`. Would it be possible to figure out `event.target` somehow when I click on the `containerFrame` and see if the element that was clicked on was inside the `containerFrame` (that red div)? The handler for `containerFrame` is outside the plugin and so figuring out `event.target` would be outside the plugin as well

Comment: @user1240679 How would you figure out the box is red? There must be something you could use here.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need something like that:

```
document.getElementById("containerFrame").onclick = function() {
    // put your function here
};
```

Comment: Please look in the fiddle. I think there's a gap in what you understood.